# Problem with the use of parameter method in scipy.interpolate.interpn

Tags: scipy, interpolation, cubic

scipy.interpolate.interpn(points, values, xi, method='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=nan)[source]

The data dimension I want to interpolate is three-dimensional. The dimensions are like this

[90, 180, 8]. When the parameter method is set to 'cubic', an error will be reported：ValueError: interpn only understands the methods 'linear', 'nearest', and 'splinef2d'. You provided cubic.
Why? Does 3D data not support such parameter settings?

I want to realize cubic Spline interpolation interpolation of 3D data.

Comment: Is that an exact copy of the error message? I ask because I'm wondering if maybe you misspelled cubic in your actual code. The documentation says that cubic is an option.

Comment: After upgrading to 1.10, “cubic” can now be used. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your scipy version: the cubic mode was only added in scipy 1.10.

Comment: Thank you. After upgrading to 1.10, “cubic” can now be used.

Comment: @sangyc10 To accept this answer, click on the gray check to the left of the answer to make it a green check.